# Google Apps Script to get the current selected image mime type

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a Google Doc file where I need to determine the MIME type of the file

I didnt find any methods that can get the mime type of the selected (SELECT USING SINGLE ON THE IMAGE USING MOUSE) image.

[image]

I have tried with

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docText = doc.editAsText();
  var content = docText.getSelection();
```

But it will not get the image type. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try opening the file with DriveApp and using getMimeType();

Comment: I need to determine the mime type of the selected image inside the Google Doc editor.

Comment: From inlineImage  you can use getBlob().getContentType()

Comment: Why dont you suggest a code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method for Document [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getselection) instead of using `editAsText()`.

Then from the selection you will get a range, from that range you get the elements it has. In this case since it is only one image it should have only one element, but you can use a for loop to treat all the elements of the range.

This is a simplified version without the for loop:

```js
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var selection = doc.getSelection()
  var range = selection.getRangeElements();
  Logger.log(range[0].getElement().getType())
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on @Cooper comment you can use his method shared with the one on this answer as:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var selection = doc.getSelection()
  var range = selection.getRangeElements();
  var image = range[0].getElement();
  Logger.log(image.getBlob().getContentType())
}
```

This will return `image/jpeg`

Comment: Please read the question carefully, we need mime type and not object type. Secondly the selection is pertained only to image.